# Interchangeability of も and と to emphasize size

Tags: particles, particle-と, particle-も

Both も and と, when used with counters, emphasize the size of the amount being mentioned. From what I've learned, も usually emphasizes how "large" it is while と emphasizes how "small" something is. I would like to know if も can replace と in contexts where the sentence is emphasizing the insignificance of the counter.

For example, for this sentence:

> 一分とかからない 
> It won't even take a minute.

> 一分もかからない 
> It won't even take a minute.

Would replacing と with も here sound natural? If it does, are there any changes in nuances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel the latter も more colloquial or casual.

と in this case cannot be used with positive predicate, so †1分とかかる is ungrammatical. This property may lead the feeling that と emphasizes "small"ness.